# Usage of "steeped": [steeped in uniqueness] and [steeped in creativity]

Tags: word-usage

(1) The small, old town is **steeped in** uniqueness.

(2) Artists and writers are always **steeped in** creativity.

Are the sentences with "steeped in" OK?

Comment: The phrases "steeped in uniqueness" and "steeped in creativity" seem awkward, strained, and possibly wrong.  One problem (among various problems) is that "steeped" is sort of literary. You are using it in the most basic of sentences "X is Y".  If you instead wrote "The small old town, steeped in uniqueness, and surrounded by unusual (somethings) ... " then it starts to seem more plausible.  Or not.  Even then, does "uniqueness" go with "steeped"?  A single object is unique.  An entire town, everywhere you look, is not.
What is the full paragraph of text?

Comment: "steep" implies "being soaked in".  It's an *external* influence.  However, creativity and uniqueness are often more *internal* qualities, don't you think? or, "imbued with creativity"